# Why is the Python terminal saying my .dat file does not exist?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I use Spyder, I have no problems, but when I copy the same code to Jupyter Notebook it says it doesn't exist.

```
my_var = {None:None}
f = open("top_secret_file.dat", "rb")
my_var = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Loading file:

```py
f = open("top_secret_file.dat", "wb")
pickle.dump(my_var, f)
f.close()
```

Writing data into file:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'top_secret_file.dat'
```

Comment: Are you running the code with the same working directory?

Comment: Hmmm I'll be honest, I'm just a beginner. I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: The writing operation should not raise an error, since the `w` mode will create the file if it doesn't exist. Check your current working directory in your read script by using `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: your code assumes that your dat file and your .py script is in the same folder.

Comment: Because it doesn't exist. If you are running your script with something like `foo/myScript.py`, the script is looking for `./top_secret_file.dat`, not `foo/top_secret_file.dat`.

Comment: "when I copy the same code to Jupyter Notepad" since you use a relative path, the file is going to be looked up in the "current working directory" (cwd). When starting a program via the shell (which I expect is what you do when you "use spyder")  that's the "current directory" of the shell, however jupyter notepad probably has a different cwd (I expect the "current working directory" is the one which contains the notebook).

Comment: You specified a relative file path, `"top_secret_file.dat"` (as opposed to ab *absolute* file path, like `"/Users/User/Desktop/top_secret_file.dat"`). A relative file path has to be *relative to something else*. That "something else" in this case is the current working directory. It's like when you have a folder open in a file browser. The folder you have open is the current working directory. Likewise, when you start `python`, it inherits the cwd from its environment, and relative paths resolve relative to that cwd.

Comment: Incidentally in Jupyter Notebook you can get the current directory using the `%pwd` command.

Comment: Brilliant, I've learned something new! Really appreciate all the help

Comment: Also I've never used stackoverflow before, so I don't know if everyone receives my reply. Just to be sure, thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put your `.py` file and `top_secret_file.dat` in the same folder. After that you can move to that folder by `cd` command and run it via `python` command.
run the following command on your terminal:

```sh
cd path/to/your/folder
python your_file.py (or python3 your_file.py)
```

Comment: This is in Jupyter. Does the `cd` command even exist?